# Extending a section of a coherent sheaf and homomorphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ be an affine integral scheme of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\phi:\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ be a surjective morphism of coherent sheaves on $X$. Let $f \in A$, $U:=D(f)$ the open set defined by $f$ and $s \in H^0(\mathcal{G})$. Let $s' \in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})$ be a section such that $\phi(s')=s|_U$. Does there exist an open set $V \subset X$ containing $\mathrm{Supp}(s)$ and a section $s_0 \in \Gamma(V,\mathcal{F})$ such that $\phi|_V(s_0)=s|_V$ and $s_0|_{V \cap U} =s'|_{V \cap U}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not true as posed.  Let $A=\mathbb{C}[x]$, let $f$ be $x$, let $\mathcal{F}$ be $\widetilde{A}$, and let $\mathcal{G}$ be the zero sheaf.  Let $s'$ be $1/x$.  Do you want to allow modifications of $s'$ and $s$ by multiplying by powers of $f$?

Comment: @Starr: I have edited the question slightly.

Comment: @Ron.  The answer is still no, even with the edits.  Let $\mathcal{F}$ be $\widetilde{A}\oplus \widetilde{A}$, let $\mathcal{G}$ be $\widetilde{A}$, let $\phi$ be projection onto the second factor, let $s$ be $1$ and let $s'$ be $(1/x,1)$.  If you hope for something like this to be true, you typically allow modifications of $s$ and $s'$ by multiplying by powers of $f$, cf. Lemma 5.3 of Chapter II of Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry".